# How can I access a field in an anonymous type stored in an object variable?

Tags: c#, object, struct, var, anonymous-types

Let's say I have code that looks like this:

```
    public struct Foo
    {
        public object obj;
        public Foo(int val)
        {
            obj = new {
                bar = val
            };
            Console.WriteLine(obj.bar); // Can't access bar.
        }
    }
```

Normally I see anonymous types stored in implicitly-typed variables, and their fields can be accessed just fine in that case. But I can't implicitly type with var in this case because `obj` is a field in a struct and apparently can't be initialized. So how do I access the field `bar`?

Comment: When did a structure get a default constructor? LOL

Comment: What do you mean? Are you saying it shouldn't compile without giving a struct an explicitly-defined parameterless constructor? Because it does compile without one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `dynamic` keyword:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public dynamic obj;
    public Foo(int val)
    {
        obj = new
        {
            bar = val
        };
        Console.WriteLine(obj.bar); // is accessible now
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing won't compile because `object` doesn't have a definition for `bar`. If for whatever reason you need to hold on to a reference to an anonymous type, you will need to use `dynamic`. Note that you will not have compile-time type safety and there may be a minor performance hit for doing this.

```
public struct Foo
{
    public dynamic obj;
    public Foo(int val)
    {
        obj = new {
            bar = val
        };
    }

    public void WriteMyFooBar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.bar);
    }
}
```

However, one does question the use of an anonymous type here instead of defining an interface which provides at least a getter for `bar`.

Answer (score 2):

Either You can try casting `obj` of type object to `dynamic` and then access the required value, or you can change the type of `obj` to `dynamic`.

Try this:

```
 Console.WriteLine(((dynamic)obj).bar));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dynamic` as others have suggested or you can user a "prototype" method, like this:

```
public struct Foo
{
    public object obj;
    public Foo(int val)
    {
        obj = new {
            bar = val
        };
        this.Use(new { bar = 0 }, x => Console.WriteLine(x.bar));
    }
    public void Use<T>(T prototype, Action<T> action)
    {
        action((T)this.obj);
    }
}
```

That works just fine.